# Using setTimeout to achieve a ghost writer effect in loop in browser

Tags: javascript

I was attempting to implement a function that would "type" out a message to a user. Something like "T" - wait - "Th" - wait - "Tha" ... I came up with this function, but it would wait and then update all the letters at once (instead of updating individually):

```
var tu = 'Thank you'
var timing = 1000
for (var i=0; i<=tu.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (){input.text(tu.slice(0, i))}, timing)
    timing = timing + 1000
}
```

But when I did this (don't laugh), it worked..

```
setTimeout(function (){input.text('t')}, 400)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('th')}, 800)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('tha')}, 3000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('than')}, 4000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('thank')}, 5000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('thank ')}, 6000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('thank y')}, 7000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('thank yo')}, 8000)
setTimeout(function (){input.text('thank you')}, 9000)
```

Can anybody shed light on why the loop is behaving differently than my cut-paste job?

Comment: I did laugh, sorry, but it was very helpful for explaining what you were wanting to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of a weird scoping thing in JavaScript. The `setTimeout` is getting the reference to `i`, *not the value of* `i`. The `for` loop completes before any of the `setTimeouts` execute, so all of the `setTimeout`s will use the same value for `i`, namely, `tu.length`.

You need to use a closure to fix this:

```
var tu = 'Thank you'
var timing = 1000
for (var i = 1; i <= tu.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            input.text(tu.slice(0, i))
        }, timing * i);
    })(i);
}
```

(also, as others noted, you have a boundary issue. I changed `i < tu.length` to `i <= tu.length`.)

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeZts/).

Comment: I always recommend avoiding multiple timeouts when a single interval will suffice, but this does answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `i` is in a larger scope than your function, so it's getting to 10 from the loop and being used (as 10) in every timeout.

There are ways around that, but it's better to use `setInterval` for this kind of behaviour;

```
var tu = 'Thank you'
var timing = 1000
var i=0;
var tm=setInterval(function(){
    ++i;
    input.text(tu.slice(0, i));
    if(i>=tu.length){
        clearInterval(tm);
    }
},timing)
```

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought about using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. You're right that it's much better suited for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You lose scope to the `i` in the loop. You'll have to create a function that has access to the `i` when it goes out of scope. Here's how I would do it:

```
var tu = 'Thank you',
    timing = 1000;

function doPart(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        input.text(tu.slice(0, i));
    }, i*timing);
}

function printString() {
    var i;
    for (i=1; i<tu.length; i++) {
        doPart(i);
    }
}

printString();
```

Also, I think you meant `tu.slice(0, i+1)`. Slice does from the start index up to, but not including, the end index.

Comment: tu.slice(0, i+1) is the same as using i <= tu.length in the loop declaration and relying on i as the slice. Changing the slice does not effect the fact that *all* the text is getting update at the same time.

Comment: @Yeow_Meng If you use `tu.slice(0, i + 1)` you will want to start `i` at `0` and make the end condition `i < tu.length`. If you use `tu.slice(0, i)` you will want to start `i` at `1` and make the end condition `i <= tu.length`.

Comment: @tjameson shoot - that's what you meant! the first slice would be [0,0] in the original code - Good eye! Your answer works but I have already awarded answer :(

Comment: Yeah, and the other user technically beat me with the closure idea. I missed that subtlety the first time, so I implemented it slightly differently (the way I'd actually do it in practice) than the other answer.